# Invalid Cast Exception When Trying To Filter Data Datewise Onto A DataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, datetimepicker

I want the user to be able to select a date from a datetimepicker and be able to view entries from that selected date on a datagrid.

Here is the code that I'm currently using:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //filter date wise using datetimepicker. dateadded is a column in mysql db workbench.

        mcon.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = mcon.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;  
        cmd.CommandText= "Select * from inventory_base.products where dateadded=  @dateselected";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateselected", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        cmd.Parameters["@dateSelected"].Value = dateTimePicker1.Value; 

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            mcon.Close();  

    }
```

When I run this code I'm getting an error message that reads:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Int32'.' on the da.Fill(dt) line.

Comment: The database must have the dateSelected column defined as an Integer.

Comment: What's the full exception call stack? http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/
Also the line of code `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateselected", SqlDbType.DateTime);` is wrong: the second parameter should be the _value_ of the parameter you want to add, not a `SqlDbType`.